# How to write spec for ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, specifications

My spec/models code as require 'spec_helper'

```
describe Student do
   it "should be work" do
     student = Student.find 1
     puts student.version
   end
end
```

When running the code it shows the following error..,

```
Failures:

  1) Student should be work
     Failure/Error: student = Student.find 2
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Could not find table 'students'
     # ./spec/models/student_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (require


Finished in 0.00109 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/student_spec.rb:4 # Student should be work
```

I'm having students table.Also, I'm using paper_trail gem.
After running rake db:test:prepare then it shows an error as.,

```
Failures:

  1) Student should be work
     Failure/Error: s = Student.find 1
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Student with id=1
     # ./models/student_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.02182 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./models/student_spec.rb:4 # Student should be work
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is no table *students* in test environment, try to run
`$ bundle exec rake db:test:prepare`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have propagated some data in your test database (using fixtures or something like FactoryGirl gem)?
Otherwise you wouldn't find any "students" in your DB.

Test-DB and Development DB have nothing in common. In fact the Test-DB will be cleared for each test.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there is no studend with id=1 in the students table of the test DB (the test DB is cleared before start new tests).
What do you want to test?

Maybe you want to use the before to insert a student at the start of the spec:

```
describe Student do
  before do
    @student = Student.new(:version => 15)
    @student.save
  end

  it "should be work" do
    student = Student.first
    # Test something ...
  end
end
```

The before block is run before every test, in this case you can get the first student in the (test) DB because you inserted it in the before block (but I don't know what you're trying to test and if save a student is really needed).